# Nix Flake: how to accept the Android SDK License

Tags: nix, nix-flake

I'm trying to use nix flakes for android development.

This is my flake.nix:

```
{
  description = "test";
  outputs = { self, nixpkgs }: {
    packages.x86_64-linux.hello = nixpkgs.legacyPackages.x86_64-linux.hello;
    devShell.x86_64-linux = nixpkgs.legacyPackages.x86_64-linux.mkShell {
      buildInputs = [
        nixpkgs.legacyPackages.x86_64-linux.androidenv.androidPkgs_9_0.androidsdk
      ];
    };
  };
}
```

Running `nix develop` gives me this message:

```
       You must accept the following licenses:
         - android-sdk-license

       by setting nixpkgs config option 'android_sdk.accept_license = true;'.
```

How can I pass this option to `nixpkgs` when using flakes?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`legacyPackages` does not let you pass `config`. You have to call Nixpkgs yourself:

```hs
outputs = { self, nixpkgs, ... }:
  let pkgs = import nixpkgs {
        system = "x86_64-linux";
        config = {
          android_sdk.accept_license = true;
        };
  };
  in { /* ... */ pkgs.androidenv.androidPkgs_9_0.androidsdk
# ...
```